# Changing MonoDevelop Encapsulation Template

Tags: monodevelop

Is it possible to change the template used by MonoDevelop when you right click a field in C# select Refactor -> Encapsulate Field?

I would like to change the default code that is inserted when this option is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a template, it's [a method](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/master/main/src/addins/CSharpBinding/MonoDevelop.CSharp.Refactoring/CSharpCodeGenerator.cs#L547) that constructs a property to match your code formatting settings.

What do you want to change? If it's something that should be influenced by code formatting settings, please [file an enhancement bug](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com).

Comment: Ah thanks, I assumed that method used a template rather than doing it all directly. I want to have curly braces start on a new line by default, so is this possible to change using an existing MonoDevelop setting?

Comment: Yes. You'll want to edit your C# code formatting policy. Assuming you're using MD 2.6+, you can use the Preference to edit the "default policy" that'll be used for new solutions. To change the policy for existing solutions, look in the solution options. You can also use the "custom policies" dialog to define new named policies.

Comment: I'm using 2.4.2 to work with Unity3D, since I don't think MD 2.6 works with it properly. Are there any workarounds for pre 2.6 releases?